# Error message when implenting usb/serial module as described by Kaz (May 31, 2013)

Tags: drivers

I received this message:

```
WARNING!! all config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper, it will be ignored in future release.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 also and was trying to install the 'pl2303' module. Why would I get this message when all else seems the same? I'm not ready to upgrade to 14 yet so I hope there is a simple answer here.

Thanks.
Tony

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning that the names of your configuration files will change.

You would need to rename the file from foo to foo.conf

You can ignore the message for now but rename it when you upgrade (or now if you prefer).